# TikZ: draw a Neural Network with two sets of outputs layers

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I have the following TikZ code, which produces a Neural Network figure. However, I would like to have two sets of different output layers. The first one running from `g_{1}` to `g_{J}`, and the other running from `s_{1}` to `s_{T}`, both separated by three vertical dots. Could you suggest some modifications to my program? Thank you very much for your time.

#### Desired output

[image]

---

#### Current result

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for aligned
%\usepackage{amssymb} % for \mathbb
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % for \ifthen
\usepackage{listofitems} % for \readlist to create arrays
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % for arrow size
\usepackage[outline]{contour} % glow around text
\contourlength{1.4pt}

\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{myred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{myblue}{blue!80!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!60!black}
\colorlet{myorange}{orange!70!red!60!black}
\colorlet{mydarkred}{red!30!black}
\colorlet{mydarkblue}{blue!40!black}
\colorlet{mydarkgreen}{green!30!black}
\tikzstyle{node}=[thick,circle,draw=myblue,minimum size=22,inner sep=0.5,outer sep=0.6]
\tikzstyle{node in}=[node,green!20!black,draw=mygreen!30!black,fill=mygreen!25]
\tikzstyle{node hidden}=[node,blue!20!black,draw=myblue!30!black,fill=myblue!20]
\tikzstyle{node convol}=[node,orange!20!black,draw=myorange!30!black,fill=myorange!20]
\tikzstyle{node out}=[node,red!20!black,draw=myred!30!black,fill=myred!20]
\tikzstyle{connect}=[thick,mydarkblue] %,line cap=round
\tikzstyle{connect arrow}=[-{Latex[length=4,width=3.5]},thick,mydarkblue,shorten <=0.5,shorten >=1]
\tikzset{ % node styles, numbered for easy mapping with \nstyle
  node 1/.style={node in},
  node 2/.style={node hidden},
  node 3/.style={node out},
}
\def\nstyle{int(\lay<\Nnodlen?min(2,\lay):3)} % map layer number onto 1, 2, or 3

\begin{document}


% NEURAL NETWORK with coefficients, shifted
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.2cm,y=1.4cm]
  \message{^^JNeural network, shifted}
  \readlist\Nnod{4,5,3} % array of number of nodes per layer
  \readlist\Nstr{q,m,J} % array of string number of nodes per layer
%\readlist\Cstr{\strut Z_{\index},w_{\index}^{(\prev)},g_{n,\index}^{}} 
\readlist\Cstr{\strut \boldsymbol{z }_{\index},w_{\index}^{(\prev)},\boldsymbol{g}_{\index}^{}} 
  \def\yshift{0.5} % shift last node for dots
  
  \message{^^J  Layer}
  \foreachitem \N \in \Nnod{ % loop over layers
    \def\lay{\Ncnt} % alias of index of current layer
    \pgfmathsetmacro\prev{int(\Ncnt-1)} % number of previous layer
    \message{\lay,}
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\c=int(\i==\N); \y=\N/2-\i-\c*\yshift;
                 \index=(\i<\N?int(\i):"\Nstr[\lay]");
                 \x=\lay; \n=\nstyle;}] in {1,...,\N}{ % loop over nodes
      % NODES
      \node[node \n] (N\lay-\i) at (\x,\y) {$\Cstr[\lay]$};

      
      % CONNECTIONS
      \ifnum\lay>1 % connect to previous layer
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\Nnod[\prev]}{ % loop over nodes in previous layer
          \draw[connect,white,line width=1.2] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
          \draw[connect] (N\prev-\j) -- (N\lay-\i);
          %\draw[connect] (N\prev-\j.0) -- (N\lay-\i.180); % connect to left
        }
      \fi % else: nothing to connect first layer
      
    }
    \path (N\lay-\N) --++ (0,1+\yshift) node[midway,scale=1.5] {$\vdots$};
  }
  % LABELS
  \node[above=5,align=center,mygreen!60!black] at (N1-1.90) {input\\[-0.2em]layer};
  \node[above=1,align=center,myblue!60!black] at (N2-1.90) {hidden layer};
  \node[above=10,align=center,myred!60!black] at (N\Nnodlen-1.90) {output\\[-0.2em]layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365404/, it may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is made from scratch, so you'll probably want to change colors, line width, etc. I made a couple of styles just for this. I'm using the Ti*k*Z `calc` library for placing the `\vdots` (easier this way). The rest is just repeating each element with a `\foreach` loop

The code:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % for placing the \vdots

\tikzset
{% styles
   my nodes/.style={circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=8mm},
   input/.style={my nodes,draw=green!50!black,fill=green!20,text=green!50!black},
   hidden/.style={my nodes,draw=violet,fill=violet!20,text=violet},
   output/.style={my nodes,draw=red!60!black,fill=red!20,text=red!60!black},
   my text/.style={text=#1,text width=1cm,align=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% grid
%\draw[gray!30] (0,1) grid[step=0.5] (5,-9.5);
% nodes, input layer
\foreach\i in {1,2,3}
  \node[input]  (z\i)  at (0,-1.5*\i)       {$z_\i$};
\node[input]    (z4)   at (0,-7)            {$z_q$};
% nodes, hideen layer
\foreach\i in {1,2,3,4}
  \node[hidden] (w\i)  at (2.5,0.75-1.5*\i) {$w_\i^{(1)}$};
\node[hidden]   (w5)   at (2.5,-7.75)       {$w_m^{(1)}$};
% nodes, output layer
\foreach\i in {1,2}
{
  \node[output] (g\i)  at (5,2-1.5*\i)      {$g_\i$};
  \node[output] (s\i)  at (5,-4-1.5*\i)     {$s_\i$};
}
\node[output]   (g3)   at (5,-3)            {$g_J$};
\node[output]   (s3)   at (5,-9)            {$s_T$};
% lines
\foreach\i in {1,2,3,4,5} \foreach\j in {1,2,3,4}
{
  \draw[violet,thick]   (w\i) -- (z\j);
  \ifnum\j<4
    \draw[violet,thick] (w\i) -- (g\j);
    \draw[violet,thick] (w\i) -- (s\j);
  \fi
}
% dots
\foreach\i/\j in {z3/z4,w4/w5,g2/g3,g3/s1,s2/s3}
  \node at ($(\i)!0.5!(\j)$) {\strut$\vdots$};
% labels
\node[my text=green!70!black]  at (0,-0.5)   {input layer};
\node[my text=violet!70!black] at (2.5,0.25) {hidden layer};
\node[my text=red!70!black]    at (5,1.5)    {output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]